# writing proper Czech quotation marks

Tags: quote, typography

I am looking for a way to write proper [Czech quotation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark), e.g., „…“ ‚…‘ »…« ›…‹, in some text modes. I found `typo.el` and `typopunct.el`. But it seems I would have to make some modifications to either of them if I wanted Czech quotation marks. Is there any other package that would be useful to achieve this beside the two?

Comment: If you do changes to typo.el to support Czech, please do consider providing a patch so I can add it to the official repo. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @JorgenSchäfer: I have made the changes and sent a pull request on GitHub.

Comment: @wilx could you possibly write a short answer to your own question, so this won't haunt the "Unanswered questions" list forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @wilx could you possibly write a short answer to your own question, so this won't haunt the "Unanswered questions" list forever?

OK. I have checked out both of the packages and I have modified both and added Czech quotation marks to them ([`typopunct-mode`](https://github.com/wilx/typopunct/blob/master/typopunct.el), [`typo-mode`](https://github.com/wilx/typoel)). My modification of `typo-mode` is already [merged to upstream](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/typoel/pull/6). I am now using `typo-mode` as it seems overall more useful. Both were easy to merge. (Also, it turned out that German quotation marks are the same as Czech quotation marks.)